# Load third party module with config (forRoot) in library module

Tags: angular, typescript

## Case:

so I've got this scenario when my app consist of at least three main projects and one shared library between them (all created via cli@ng7). 
Thing is: this library import other third party library and utilize forRoot method same as mine SharedLibrary

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({ apiKey: 'some-api-key' })
    ],
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent,
    ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        AgmCoreModule,
        HeaderComponent,
    ]
})
export class SharedLibraryModule {
    static forRoot(
        config: SharedLibraryConfig = new SharedLibraryConfig()
    ): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedLibraryModule,
            providers: [
                SharedLibraryService,
                {
                    provide: SharedConfigToken,
                    useValue: config
                }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

## Problem

So basically above is my SharedLibraryModule (S) which is consumed by my host Projects (H) (apps) via `SharedLibraryModule.forRoot()` 
I need to pass values from host apps to 
`AgmCoreModule.forRoot({ apiKey: 'some-api-key' }) // <- here`

( H -> S -> 3rdparty module )

... so far I come up with two solutions, first one partially works, second don't

## Solution #1

This one is quite hacky I presume. Main idea is to get value from config argument and modify class body with it. So basically it's after decoration but before instance creation:

```js
// it's poc/draft so don't ask about quality please :)

export class SharedLibraryModule {
    static forRoot(
        config: SharedLibraryConfig = new SharedLibraryConfig()
    ): ModuleWithProviders {
        const module = SharedLibraryModule['decorators'][0].args[0] as NgModule;
        const agm = module.imports.find(
            item => item['ngModule'] && item['ngModule'].name === 'AgmCoreModule'
        );
        const agmConf = agm['providers'].find(
            item => item && item.useValue && item.useValue.apiKey
        );
        agmConf.useValue.apiKey = 'other value';
        return {
            ngModule: SharedLibraryModule,
            providers: [
                SharedLibraryService,
                {
                    provide: SharedConfigToken,
                    useValue: config
                }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

*problem:* actually it works, didn't test it in prod though. I don't know if it will work with services and interceptors as I need to provide few as well. I believe it's a hacky method, correct me if I wrong (I think I need to Inject it here more angular way.

## Solution #2

it's not working for now - but idea is to wrap all in function (create factory of some sort) on return it creates module and pass to `AgmCoreModule.forRoot({ apiKey: 'some-api-key' })` specific arguments

```js
export const SHARED_MODULE = (
    CONFIG: SharedLibraryConfig = new SharedLibraryConfig()
): ModuleWithProviders => {
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            CommonModule,
            FormsModule,
            AgmCoreModule.forRoot({ apiKey: 'some-api-key' })
        ],
        declarations: [HeaderComponent],
        exports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, AgmCoreModule, HeaderComponent]
    })
    export class SharedLibraryModule {
        static forRoot(
            config: SharedLibraryConfig = new SharedLibraryConfig()
        ): ModuleWithProviders {
            return {
                ngModule: SharedLibraryModule,
                providers: [
                    SharedLibraryService,
                    {
                        provide: SharedConfigToken,
                        useValue: config
                    }
                ]
            };
        }
    }
}
```

*problem:* this actually completely not working. I don't think class decorators can be used like this. webpack on compilation says that component can't be found.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why you just cannot import **AgmCoreModule.forRoot** in your **Host** projects? and in library import **AgmCoreModule** without **forRoot** config.

Comment: sorry, for sake of example I just put only one situation. I assume I will put some extra communication layer (like firebase or something, thru this) or actually anything - I want to strip more logic to one shared module. you're right - I should put in this context in host, however I'm talking about bigger case in here :)